# How to Implement Invitation Codes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web application built in asp.net mvc using forms authentication.

I am wondering how to properly implement a system in which new users must enter an invitation code in order to create an account on my site.

Basically, I want to use the out of the box Account Controller and models as much as possible for account creation.

Do I just need to block access to the Registration page if a user does not enter a valid invite code?

Any examples on how to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the easiest solution would be to just make confirmation code a required field on the Registration page. However, I feel that this is not the most elegant way to solve this problem.

Another idea: Have the Registation page GET method take InviteCode as a parameter(passed in the query string) and redirect to another page if the code is null or invalid. Does anyone see any problems with this approach?

Comment: One option, you could make invitation code a required field on the register viewmodel.

Comment: This was my initial thought, but was really wondering if there were any  cleaner ways to accomplish this. This will most likely be my back-up plan. Ultimately I would have to have a TextBox on the Home page for the user to enter the invite code and be directed to the registration page if it is valid

Comment: Like Adam says, you're going to need to add a field to the register viewmodel, and validation against it. Or you could store the valid invitation code in TempData, and then look for it in the Register GET action method. Either way, you're going to have to change from the oob code. Would you rather change the viewmodel or the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an end user, I would want to enter in the code before I ever get to my account details. If I enter them in only to find out I have an invalid code, I'd be pretty angry.

So your options would likely be:

1. They enter up front (as mentioned on the reg page)
2. Enter them on the same registration page, hiding applicable form elements.
   2a. Reg code is checked by ajax, and account details appear.

Reg code is posted along with account details for additional verification.

Remote validation can be used, json calls, etc to check the field.

Remote validation: http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/08/remote-ajax-validation-in-mvc3.html

or a json call to validate, or front page, or..
the options here are really up to you. The validation of the token should be easy enough and doesn't have to be related at all to your account code.

Comment: I agree, my registration page is completed before any substantial profile info is given(this happens on a different page)